# Use ApplicationBar Icons from other assemblies?

Tags: windows-phone-7, appbar

I have a Page in a Windows Phone class library. This page has an appbar. I would prefer everything this page needs to be included within the class library so the setup list for consumers of this page / assembly is minimal.

However, When I set ApplicationBar icons, they get added to the class library project under the folder 'icons' just like normal, they show up fine in Blend, but at runtime they are no where to be found!

When I put the icons in the Windows Phone Application project all is well. However this is not my desired scenario as it is additional configuration / setup by the application author to use my pages.

I tried using the resource pathing using /{AssemblyName};component/icons/{IconName} but of course the AppBar needs them to be of type "Content" not "Resource". So I am thinking this is impossible but I wanted to know if anybody out there figured out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys. I just figured it out. I changed the newly added icons from "Resource" to "Content" but I forgot to set "Copy if newer" so they weren't getting outputted to the Bin\Debug\icons folder of the windows Phone Application. something to keep an eye on I guess.

Comment: Actually it's helpful, I think I ran into the same issue but I just left the icons in the main assembly. I'll have to go back and pull them back out now. Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I came to find out that this only works when the external assembly is a Project reference (i.e. it builds with the Phone App project). So if you are using it as a completely external assembly, like I am, you are back to copying to the Phone App project anyway. :(